# How come Xorg refuses to generate an xorg.conf file for me?

Tags: 11.10, xorg, intel-graphics

I have a DisplayLink monitor that I am trying to add to my Ubuntu desktop. After plugging it in, the screen turns completely green, which I understand means that the DisplayLink kernel module is installed and can interface with the device.

Adding the monitor to my `xorg.conf` shouldn't be too hard except there *is* no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Apparently I have to generate one - so that's what I tried to do with the following command:

```
Xorg -configure
```

However, this seems to be failing. Here is the output of the command:

```
X.Org X Server 1.10.4
Release Date: 2011-08-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-29-server x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux my-machine 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic root=UUID=e2b7e4b2-720a-4ea7-af1c-3757f4c36bfc ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 29 September 2011  02:45:13AM
xorg-server 2:1.10.4-1ubuntu4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.22.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Oct 15 14:07:13 2011
List of video drivers:
    siliconmotion
    radeon
    displaylink
    qxl
    s3
    sis
    neomagic
    trident
    tdfx
    r128
    vmwlegacy
    ati
    vmware
    nouveau
    mga
    intel
    savage
    openchrome
    mach64
    cirrus
    sisusb
    fbdev
    vesa
(EE) Failed to load module "vmwgfx" (module does not exist, 0)
(EE) vmware: Please ignore the above warnings about not being able to to load module/driver vmwgfx
(EE) vmware: Unexpected failure while loading the "vmwlegacy" driver. Giving up.
(EE) Failed to load module "vmware" (a required submodule could not be loaded, 0)
(++) Using config file: "/home/nathan/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
```

Here is the output of `sudo lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation N10 Family DMI Bridge
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 02)
0    0:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

Answer (score 1):

The vmware graphics driver (vmwgfx) is an external add on driver by VMWare, not one supported by core X.org.  `Xorg -configure` really is only valid for the core official drivers.